# NA value getting converted to NULL while exporting the data from Excel to PostgreSQL

Tags: python, excel, postgresql

While exporting the data from Excel to POSTGRESQL, Values NA get converted to NULL.It should be there as NA.
I am using python for the transfer with the below code.

```
try:
    df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Projects\MLT\File.xlsx")
    # print(df.head(10))
    print(df.shape[0])
except Exception as error:
    print(error,'Unable to Read the Data')


# Create Alchemy Engine to write the data of dataframe on table
try:
    engine   = create_engine('params')
    df.to_sql('table',engine,if_exists='append',schema='schema_name', index=False)
except Exception as error:
    print(error,'Unable to Insert the Data')
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix for this, By Default Pandas process NA to Nan resulting in NULL.
we can use

```
keep_default_na=False
```

So now Read the like below:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\Projects\MLT\File.xlsx",keep_default_na=False)
```

and this will fix the issue.
Reference: [Pandas.Read_CSV](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)